# why my calculated cant be applied in my filters tableau

Tags: tableau-api

this is my tableau workbook

[image]

so i want to calculate day different between each transaction for each users, the users on this case are in filters PUL: True with this calculation

```
{Fixed [User Id]: sum(
if [Created At]<=[END_DATE] then 1 else 0 end)}>=2
AND
{FIXED [User Id]: sum(
IF [Created At]<=[END_DATE] AND 
[Created At] >= [START_DATE] THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)}>=1
```

it means the users with more than 1 transaction before last range and atleast doing 1 transaction in date range are on the list.

so after that i made calculated field to count day different with this formula [CF]

```
DATEDIFF('day',LOOKUP(MIN([Created At]),-1), MIN([Created At]))
```

and also i made filters date range

```
lookup(min(([Created At])),0) >= [START_DATE] and 
lookup(min(([Created At])),0) <= [END_DATE]
```

so not only count the time difference in date range for selected users, but each users also count day different on last transaction before date range (if any)

so this is the results (please take a look at user_id 86886)

[image]

i didnt understand why user_id 86886 as my experiments only have 1 transaction instead i already made the filters that only take user who doing transaction more than 1, after i check it, that user_id 86886 are doing more than 1 transaction in a day. this is the screenshoot

[image]

my questions is

1. why the tableau cant visualize all of the transaction in same day (but different hour) like this

[image]

and how to visualize it so it will appear 2 records with same day but different hour.

2. and also why if the transaction on the same day count time different with NULL instead it should be 0 because there's no time different

[image]

EXPECTED RESULTS (let's take a case in user_id 86886)

```
+---------+-----------------------+-------------+
| user_Id |    dayOfCreatedAt     | CF diff day |
+---------+-----------------------+-------------+
|   86886 | 1/25/2020 11:25:28 AM |             |
|         | 1/25/2020 11:39:42 AM |          0  |
+---------+-----------------------+-------------+
```

explanations : the first one of CF diff day become NULL because it's first transaction of this user, and the user is not doing transaction again before that, and the second was "0" because there's no day different, the different was only in hour, but although it was same day, so there will be not different day and it count 0

based on @Anil advice, this is my link of workbook tableau https://public.tableau.com/profile/fachry.dzaky#!/vizhome/simulation_data/Sheet14

Comment: A small advice, you can post a link of your Tableau public workbook so that the experts on SO not aware of that, may propose something better and new solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your PUL field has some errors.  Probably you should change the calculation of this field as

```
{Fixed [User Id]: sum(
if [Created At]<[START_DATE] then 1 else 0 end)}>=1
AND
{FIXED [User Id]: sum(
IF [Created At]<=[END_DATE] AND 
[Created At] >= [START_DATE] THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)}>=1
```

Because, if you are trying to get non-null difference there must be at least one transaction before the `[start_date]`.  **Check it please.**

Now please follow these steps (carefully please)

**Step-1** Drag `user id` and `created at` at **Rows Shelf**.

**Step-2** Change `created at` to *exact date* and thereafter to *discreet* (**Both are important and you view shows that you haven't displayed it as exact date and as day of *created_at* instead**)

**Step-3**: Set you date parameters

**Step-4** Drag all three desired fields to filters shelf.

**Step*5**: Add `PUL` to context (again an important step)

**Step-6** double click the `CF` field (check its calculation as

```
DATEDIFF('day', LOOKUP(MIN([Created At]),-1), MIN([Created At]))
```

**Step-7** Change table calculation options of `CF` as table down (**check this is also important**)

**Step-8** double click other CF_max/Min fields to add these to `measure values`

**Step-9** change table calculation options in each of these four fields as discussed earlier (i.e. nested calculation of `CF` as `specific dimensions` restarting at every user_id).  And nested calculation of CF_Max(as the case may be) to table down.

**NOte** Regarding you specific problem of user_id `86886` (if I will remove PUL revised condition as `TRUE` I am getting the same view as desired).  Have a look please

[image]

Comment: So basically the problems I can identify are (i) day(createdAt) instead of exact date & discreet, (ii) the table calculation options in CF and (iii) table calculation options in nested calculations of all four fields where you have to fix these both aggregated field and CF.

Comment: i think your calculation of PUL it's  wrong, because when the users are doing transaction more than 1 in date range (between start_date and end_date) then it will become not on the list, instead its should be, because as long as the users are doing transaction for more than 1 transaction, and have atleast 1 transaction on the date  range, its should be on PUL list

Comment: and also, there's no minus different day between each transaction of PUL users, because it will see the last transaction before first transaction in range (if any), but if didn't and it's first transaction, then the diff day should be 0. thats why you suggest me on date range put the calculations like this `lookup(min(([Created At])),0) >= [START_DATE] and 
lookup(min(([Created At])),0) <= [END_DATE]`

Comment: i think it can be `NULL` if the first transaction which on date range, are the first transaction of that users, so it means that there's no transaction before (take a look at my expected results). `0` diff day happen when 2 transactions or more in same user_id are doing in same day, so it can be `0` value of diff day like the expected results

Comment: I thought that you may have required PUL like that.  Anyways you have PUL calculation as per scenario required.  Nevertheless the view will work if you'll apply calculations as explained. Take note of each step carefully please.